# Magento 2: Invoice quantity of order is wrong after payment successfully

Tags: magento2

**I got an issue with my order like this image.**

[image: Error]

It's missing invoiced status in Qty column of order item table but invoiced has already created after payment successfully (I've checked mollie.log) so order still has processing status even that I've made a shipment.
It happens rarely for me, but I have 02 orders, which they appear.
Please help me fix it.

**My Magento platform version: 2.3.3
My mollie payment module version: 1.4.3**

**Reproduce step:**

> 1. Order product
> 2. Payment via Ideal
> 3. Check order in Magento backend.